# object stop falling when reach a specific point in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am making a game in which the balls are falling down on a plane one ball fall over the other ball and they make a line, which goes from bottom to top. I want that at certain point on y axis the ball stop falling. Don't know how to do it the code I used until now for balls to fall down is:

```
function calling(){
    functionsRandom.Range(0, functions.Length);
}

function sphereA() { 
    var go = Instantiate(sphere,new Vector3(Random.Range(-3, 3),Random.Range(-3,3),-12.78451),Quaternion.identity);
    go.renderer.material.color = Color(Random.value, Random.value, Random.value);    
}

function sphereB() { 
    var go = Instantiate(sphere1,new Vector3(Random.Range(-3, 3),Random.Range(-3,3),-12.78451),Quaternion.identity);
    go.renderer.material.color = Color(Random.value, Random.value, Random.value);
}
```

I used random.range, so that the ball falls from points between it both in x and y, for x it is working, but it is not working for y.

Comment: What in this code is making your spheres fall? Are you using `RigidBody` physics?

Comment: yes spheres fall and i am using RigidBody physics.

Answer (score 0):

Add all the instantiated spheres to an array `go[]` instead of `go`. which are in line. Now at certain point where you want to stop generating other spheres, take the count of the sphere in the array. If the count is equal to the max limit. Then DON'T instantiate the spheres. If any doubts, come to [unity3d chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37624/unity3d-developers).